Making Dictionary From Online Usable on Kindle
I've spent many hours on separate days throughout the past few months trying to get this dictionary to work on my Kindle Paperwhite but I simply can't figure it out. This is the dictionary:
https://archive.org/details/RussianEnglishRussianDictionary
Tried converting to .mobi in Calibre from .epub, changing the formatting in under the 'edit book', converting from .pdf to .epub and then putting it into Kindle Previewer and quite literally dozens of other things I can no longer remember. The problem is that for a dictionary to work on kindle it has to be in .mobi format but pdf's don't convert properly to mobi files and the epub's format from the site is all messed up.
If anyone is able to make it so it's formatted exactly how it is in the pdf version or at least so that it can work properly as a .mobi I'd be eternally grateful. Can't buy an even half decent .mobi English-Russian dictionary because they don't exist on Amazon or anywhere I've looked. It's honestly strange how hard it is to get a good English-Russian dictionary onto Kindle; the default one is pretty terrible and doesn't have many basic words. Thanks, please help lol.
